# Fail to scan integers from a text file

Tags: c

I have a text file that looks like that:

```
coordinate      size    average Intensity
==========      ====    =================
(187,18)        31      217.8
(58,29)         34      212.1
(124,71)    47  216.1
(245,71)    32  197.8
(96,113)    30  191.6
(244,135)   33  199.6
```

Im trying to receive only the 'size' to a variable but for some reason im not able to do so. This is the code i tried:

```
FILE * textofGags;
int xx;    
fopen_s(&textOfGags,"dust.txt","rt");
fseek(textOfGags,0L,SEEK_SET);
fscanf_s(textOfGags,"%*[^\n]\n,",NULL);
fscanf_s(textOfGags,"%*[^\n]\n,",NULL);
while(fscanf_s(textOfGags,"%d",&xx)==1){
    printf("%d",xx);
    fscanf_s(textOfGags,"%*[^\n]\n,",NULL);
}
```

For now im just trying to print in order to see where the problem is but it seems that i cant even receive the number. Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: I think you forget C+, C-, C{} and C##

Comment: C/C++ is also always fun. And my prefered language: Brainfuck should never be missing.

Comment: @Olaf Or at least malbolge :-P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I prefer Balrogs. Maybe we should keep some to haunt posters of bad questions if we are out of CVs?

Comment: Forget this piece of code. Rewrite it in plain C++ as tagged.

Comment: @user1587451 What's tagged c++?

Comment: @user1587451: If you only have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail …

Comment: @xing thank you it actually works. Can you give me a short explanation of what (%*d ,%*d ) is doing?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you got some downvotes for wrong tagging :-)
Anyway, I think we should help each other.

The code looks a little bit complicated to me, and - even with a debugger - it is probably hard to find out whether an `fscanf("%*[^\n]\n," ...` moves the file position actually to the right place;

I suggest to read in the file line by line, then analyse each line based on it's specific content, and read in the size. For example, one might use the fact that the size-value is the first integral value after a closing `')'`, and lines without such a `')'` may be ignored.

Hope it helps :-)

```
int main() {

    FILE * textofGags;
    int xx;
    textofGags = fopen("dust.txt","rt");
    if (textofGags) {
        char line[1000];
        while (fgets(line,1000,textofGags)) {

            char *closingBrace = strchr(line, ')');
            if (!closingBrace)
                continue;

            closingBrace++; // first char after the ')'
            if (sscanf(closingBrace,"%d",&xx) == 1) {
                printf("size: %d \n", xx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```